# How to add an expanded button when text is long?

Tags: reactjs

In my react app,I have a bio section along with name and when someone's bio is long,I am displaying ('...').
To achieve this,I used css text-overflow property.
Here is the CSS code

```
.about-me {
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    }
```

But now I want to add an arrow button and when someone clicks it ,It should display the entire text.

```
            <div>
              <span className="about-me">{(extraInfo && extraInfo.aboutMe) || ''}</span>
            </div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Here is an image for reference

[image]

Comment: Do you need like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-nz0j8

Comment: Yes.
But there is one change needed.
The more button shouldn't be displayed when text length is 30

Comment: You can make the condition check like:   ```{extraInfo && extraInfo.aboutMe && extraInfo.aboutMe.length > 30 ? (
        <button onClick={toggle}>{isOpen ? "less" : "more"}</button>
      ) : null}``` Forked sample:   https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-vgw5m

Comment: Thanks a lot.
This works perfectly.
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to display a certain number of characters, and make a condition to display short text, e.g:

***limitChar.js:***

```
function limitChar(str, limit) {
  return str.length > limit ? `${str.slice(0, limit)}...` : str;
}
```

***App.js:***

```
function App() {
  const [extraInfo, setExtraInfo] = React.useState(false);
  const text =
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
const limitCharLength = 80;

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{extraInfo ? text : limitCharacters(text. limitCharLength)}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setExtraInfo(true)}>Show More!</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

NOTE: there are some packages to do this, like [text-ellipsis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-ellipsis).

Answer (score 1):

I thank that it'll be easier to toggle  .about-me depending on the button click.

```
$( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
```

[Jquery Official Docs](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

But if you prefer using CSS I've something for you :
[Pure Css: Checked toggle class](https://codepen.io/cristina-silva/pen/pyXQrj)

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to apply another class to the same div upon the user clicking 'read more'

This class should apply the `none` value to the `line-clamp` property that stops the text-overflow and ellipses from occurring.

Your css will be something like:

```
.about-me.show-all {
      -webkit-line-clamp: none;
    }
```

and so long as you apply the 'show-all' class via JS code that should work, as the CSS is more specific.

Also, just a general note that you should review if your CSS will work across browsers and if you should use a different approach to get text-overflow working as you desire if you need broad browser support.